# can't run Java program PitchShift with TarsosDSP

Tags: java, pitch-shifting, tarsosdsp

I am trying to run the Pitch Shifting example here:

https://0110.be/posts/Pitch_Shifting_-_Implementation_in_Pure_Java_with_Resampling_and_Time_Stretching

but I can't get it to work. I try to run

java -jar PitchShift-latest.jar

from the command line but I get this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class be.tarsos.dsp.example.PitchShiftingExample

I can't run it from Eclipse either. Any suggestions?